# Why doesn't input integer match integer literal in code?

Tags: python

Please, give me answer - whats wrong in this code? i didn't see anyway word "ok" (then 'vvod' = 'zagadkaa')

```
import random
zagadka = [1,2,3]
random.shuffle(zagadka)
print ("Please enter number between 1 and 3")

zagadkaa = zagadka.pop()
vvod = input("Enter number here")
if vvod == zagadkaa:
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("wrong %d"%zagadkaa)
print ("Goodbye")
```

then i run this script i see this:

```
Please enter number between 1 and 3
Enter number here1
wrong 1
Goodbye

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What's wrong? I'd start with the variable names. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: It works for me.  I see "ok" when I got the number correct, and "wrong" when I got it wrong.

Comment: hmm it not works for me :  Please enter number between 1 and 3
Enter number here1
wrong 1
Goodbye

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What platform/operating system are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
zagadka = [1,2,3]
random.shuffle(zagadka)
print ("Please enter number between 1 and 3")

zagadkaa = zagadka.pop()
vvod = int(raw_input("Enter number here"))   # make sure we have a number, not a string, and don't eval it.
if vvod == zagadkaa:
    print ("ok")
else:
    print ("wrong %d"%zagadkaa)
print ("Goodbye")
```

Comment: oww! work fine! thanks! but i don't understand, i reed in manual for python, that they doesn't need set type of variable :(

Comment: Normally your original code will work.   It works for me under linux and windows.    I think that you are in an environment (language/locale/operatingsystem) where the string that is  being input has some extra characters in it (unicode?).   Or maybe you entered a space?   " 1 " is not equal to "1".    You could try printing the length of it.   If you are not using Python 3 (IE you are using python 2.x) I agree with neo_blackcap that you should use raw_input().   Please read about the differences.

Comment: thanks! will check my os. really, i test this code in linux and it's work good without "vvod = int(input("enter number here"))"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should replace input() with raw_input(). Here is the input function's document

```
input([prompt])

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.
```